# Confuse in <meter> tag

Tags: javascript, php, html

can someone help me to understand the **difference** between the 2 meter
and why the **colour** **difference** between them although they have the *same* *value*
??

```html
<meter low="69" high="80" max="100" value="84">A</meter><span>MDN example</span> <br>

<meter low="30" high="80" max="100" value="84">B</meter>
```

Comment: The `low` value is different, that's the reason for the color difference.

Comment: i know that the low value of both is different but i try to say that  they have the same case like 
value > high > low
why both of them has a different colour ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is because of different low and high values.

Now the meter tag forms three regions:

One from min(0) to low, another from low to high and third from high to max(100).

Default value of optimum is 50. You can set it to whatever value you want. Now in what ever region the optimum lies that is colored green. The neighbour region is colored yellow and the farthest is colored red.

In the first example, default optimum value is 50. If I make `low=60` and `high=80`, then anything between 0 to 60 will be green, between 60 to 80 will be yellow and from 80 to 100 will be red.

In the second example, I have set the `optimum=70`, keeping the low and high value same. Then anything between 0 to 60 will be yellow, between 60 to 80 will be green and from 80 to 100 will be yellow.

```html
<p>First exmple</p>
<meter low="60" high="80" max="100" value="34">A</meter><br/>
<meter low="60" high="80" max="100" value="65">B</meter><br/>
<meter low="60" high="80" max="100" value="84">C</meter><br/>
<p>Second exmple</p>
<meter low="60" high="80" optimum="70" max="100" value="34">A</meter><br/>
<meter low="60" high="80" optimum="70" max="100" value="65">B</meter><br/>
<meter low="60" high="80" optimum="70" max="100" value="84">C</meter><br/>
```

Comment: i think both of them must be with yellow colour
that is because both of them have a value that larger than the high value ,
why ( low value ) affect on them ?

Comment: @KaremGmeay  Sorry for not adding a proper explanation. I have edited the answer take a look. Do accept the answer if it is helpful.

Comment: Do you mean that  the optimum value by default is the mid between the min and max value although not set it ?

Comment: I think what you are trying to say is if you make low 80 and high 100, then optimum value should be 90 if you dont set it. But no, the optimum value is by default 50 in any case.

Comment: please, can i speak with you on facebook or other any site you want if you don't mind
facebook/karemgmeay

Comment: @KaremGmeay sure, my email id is `anujab70092@gmail.com`

Answer (score 1):

The color difference is because of the way the meter tag compares the value to the optimum value. The following will make both meters yellow:

```html
<span>MDN example</span><br>
<meter low="69" optimum="80" high="80" max="100" value="84">A</meter><br>
<meter low="30" optimum="40" high="80" max="100" value="84">B</meter>
```

A detailed explanation about this can be found [here](https://css-tricks.com/html5-meter-element/)

Comment: but in my example the optimum value is ignored
and i try to say that they have the same case like 
value > high > low
so , why both of them has a different colour ?